# Field of fractions for semiring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In ring theory, for integral domains we can construct the field of fractions (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_fractions).

Is there correspondingly such a thing for semiring?

Thanks.

Comment: The most natural thing to do would be to add inverses to all non-zero divisors to the semiring.  Is this what you want?

Comment: I can't think of anything that acts as a barrier for the usual construction for commutative rings. Why don't you just check?

Comment: Potentially you'd have to upgrade the integral domain law $ab = 0 \rightarrow a = 0 \vee b = 0$ to the cancellation law $ab = ab' \rightarrow a = 0 \vee b=b'$. Otherwise, the inclusion into the semifield of fractions might not be injective. I suspect that with this modification, everything should go through as expected.